# Is there a way to hide all the HTTP request logs from the node terminal output?

Tags: cypress

When I run a suite of tests using Cypress, I get a TON of HTTP request logs to the terminal output. I think this image best shows the issue. In it, you can see the command I run to start cypress, and that following it comes a long list of every HTTP request made during the tests.

Is there a way to hide them all?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to `cypress.config.json`:

```js
"morgan": false,
```

The logs you see are from express (a built-in server within cypress).

Comment: this does not solve the problem and I cant find any reference to this online...

Comment: Works for me. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26284